# How to add/multiply using big.Int in Golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to write a function that returns the nth number of the Fibonacci Sequence. I am running into trouble when going from returning an int to a big.Int.

Here is the normal version, which just uses matrix exponentiation to find the nth number of the Fibonacci sequence. It works just fine and returns the value I want:

```
func normalFib(n int) int {
    if n == 0 || n == 1 {
        return n
    }
    n -= 2
    a, b, c := 1, 1, 0
    x, y := 1, 1

    var evenNum [3]int
    var oddNum [2]int
    for n > 0 {
        if n%2 == 0 {
            temp := []int{a*a + b*b, a*b + b*c, b*b + c*c}
            a, b, c = temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]
            copy(evenNum[:], temp)
            n /= 2
        } else {
            temp := []int{x*a + y*b, x*b + y*c}
            x, y = temp[0], temp[1]
            copy(oddNum[:], temp)
            n--
        }
    }
    return oddNum[0]
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(normalFib(10)) // Outputs 55
}
```

The intermediate values of the above function look like this:

```
The value of N is currently: 8 
The values of a, b, c: 2 1 1   

The value of N is currently: 4 
The values of a, b, c: 5 3 2   

The value of N is currently: 2 
The values of a, b, c: 34 21 13

The value of N is currently: 1 
The values of x, y: 55 34      // x is correct!
```

This is the big.Int version. Because of the way the big.Add() and big.Mul() functions work, I've tried working with it by

1. creating three result variables d, e, and f that will temporarily store the result of those functions for each value in the temporary array.
2. setting the values of a, b, c to the values of the slice (or x, y if it is an odd number)
3. copying the temporary slice to its respective array (evenNum or oddNum).

Despite what I've tried, it will still only output multiples of two, which is not what I want:

```
func bigFib(n int) *big.Int {
    if n == 0 || n == 1 {
        return big.NewInt(int64(n))
    }

    n -= 2
    a, b, c := big.NewInt(1), big.NewInt(1), big.NewInt(0)
    x, y := big.NewInt(1), big.NewInt(0)

    var evenNum [3]*big.Int
    var oddNum [2]*big.Int

    for n > 0 {
        if n%2 == 0 {
            // Result variables
            d, e, f := big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(0)
            // Temporary slice to hold the result of the matrix addition.
            temp := []*big.Int{
                d.Add(e.Mul(a, a), f.Mul(b, b)),
                d.Add(e.Mul(a, b), f.Mul(b, c)),
                d.Add(e.Mul(b, b), f.Mul(c, c))}
            // Setting a, b, c to the values of the slice.
            a, b, c = temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]
            // Copying the temp slice to the evenNum array.
            copy(evenNum[:], temp)
            n /= 2
        } else {
            // Result variables
            d, e, f := big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(0)
            // Temprorary slice to hold the result of the matrix addition.
            temp := []*big.Int{
                d.Add(e.Mul(x, a), f.Mul(y, b)),
                d.Add(e.Mul(x, b), f.Mul(y, c))}
            // Set x, y to the values of the slice.
            x, y = temp[0], temp[1]
            // Copying the temp slice to the oddNum array.
            copy(oddNum[:], temp)
            n--
        }
    }
    return oddNum[0]
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(bigFib(10)) // Outputs 8
}
```

The intermediate values for the bigFib function look like this:

```
The value of N is currently: 8
Value of d, e, f: 1 1 0       
Value of a, b, c: 1 1 1       

The value of N is currently: 4
Value of d, e, f: 2 1 1       
Value of a, b, c: 2 2 2       

The value of N is currently: 2
Value of d, e, f: 8 4 4       
Value of a, b, c: 8 8 8       

The value of N is currently: 1
Value of d, e, f:  8 8 0      
Value of x, y: 8 8
```

If anyone can show me what is going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the type name suggests, a `*big.Int` is a pointer, and per the documentation for `big.Int.Add`:

> Add sets z to the sum x+y and returns z.

The "returns `z`" is important, because it means that when you do this:

```
temp := []*big.Int{
    d.Add(e.Mul(a, a), f.Mul(b, b)),
    d.Add(e.Mul(a, b), f.Mul(b, c)),
    d.Add(e.Mul(b, b), f.Mul(c, c))
}
```

all three elements of your slice end up being pointers to the same `big.Int`, i.e. to `d`. Each of your three `Add` calls may change `d`, but they're all changing (and returning a pointer to) the same, single object, which is not what you want.

To avoid this behavior, you need to create a new, distinct object for each distinct result, something like:

```
temp := []*big.Int{
    big.NewInt(0).Add(big.NewInt(0).Mul(a, a), big.NewInt(0).Mul(b, b)),
    big.NewInt(0).Add(big.NewInt(0).Mul(a, b), big.NewInt(0).Mul(b, c)),
    big.NewInt(0).Add(big.NewInt(0).Mul(b, b), big.NewInt(0).Mul(c, c)),
 }
```

If you want to minimize allocations, you should be able to do:

```
x, y := big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(0)
temp := []*big.Int{
    big.NewInt(0).Add(x.Mul(a, a), y.Mul(b, b)),
    big.NewInt(0).Add(x.Mul(a, b), y.Mul(b, c)),
    big.NewInt(0).Add(x.Mul(b, b), y.Mul(c, c)),
}
```

since the `Adds` are done in order and the pointers to `x` and `y` are not retained, so the fact you're reusing copies of them doesn't cause a problem. But for the three elements of your slice, you need distinct objects.

Comment: @BillBaggins: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem to your satisfaction.